# entry_focus after messagebox how to do it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How can I fix this? I can't find out how to focus after the messagebox.
My code:

```
##########
    from tkinter import*
    from tkinter import messagebox
    def call():
        vn_info = vn.get()
        if vn_info=="":
             messagebox.showinfo("ok","test1")
             vn_entry.focus_set()

    window=Tk()
    window.geometry("500x500")

    window.title("testfocus")
    heading= Label(text= "focus", bg="grey", fg="black",width="500",height="3")
    heading.pack()

    vn_text=Label(text="Vn")

    vn_text.place(x=15,y=70)

##########

    vn=StringVar()
    vn_entry=Entry(textvariable=vn,width="30")
    vn_entry.place(x=15,y=90)
    bt=Button(window,text="call",width=30,height="2",command=call,bg="green")
    bt.place(x=15,y=280)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to `focus` your `Entry` widget?

Comment: yes that's what I want.

Comment: The entry field has focus on my side. Windows 10. Are you on a different OS?

Comment: I use windows10 and pycharm.

Comment: Well on my end your code works as expected. The focus on the entry field works fine after the pop-up message.

Comment: On my mac the focus is no longer on the 'testfocus' window after closing the messagebox.  Adding `window.focus_set()` in the call function before the `vn_entry.focus_set()` moved the focus to the window and the entry widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works fine for me. But there are two other ways which have a slight edge over the way you are trying.

**1. By Globalization:**

You can globalize your variable(`vn`) and Entry Widget(`vn_entry`) inside the function(`call`) so there are more chances that your function easily understands which variable and Entry widget to deal with.

Like This:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def call():
    global vn, vn_entry

    vn_info = vn.get()
    if vn_info == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("ok", "test1")
        vn_entry.focus_set()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("testfocus")

heading = tk.Label(window, text="focus", bg="grey", fg="black", width="500", height="3")
heading.pack()

vn_text = tk.Label(window, text="Vn")
vn_text.place(x=15, y=70)

vn = tk.StringVar()

vn_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=vn, width="30")
vn_entry.place(x=15, y=90)

bt = tk.Button(window, text="call", width=30, height="2", command=call, bg="green")
bt.place(x=15, y=280)

window.mainloop()
```

**2. By Passing Arguments:**

You can pass your variable(`vn`) and Entry Widget(`vn_entry`) to the function(`call`) as arguments so there are also more chances that your function easily understands which variable and Entry widget to deal with.

Like This:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def call(var, e):

    vn_info = var.get()
    if vn_info == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("ok", "test1")
        e.focus_set()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("testfocus")

heading = tk.Label(window, text="focus", bg="grey", fg="black", width="500", height="3")
heading.pack()

vn_text = tk.Label(window, text="Vn")
vn_text.place(x=15, y=70)

vn = tk.StringVar()

vn_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=vn, width="30")
vn_entry.place(x=15, y=90)

bt = tk.Button(window, text="call", width=30, height="2", command=lambda: call(vn, vn_entry), bg="green")
bt.place(x=15, y=280)

window.mainloop()
```

**Note:**

- You are `import`ing `*` from `tkinter`, Whereas `*` `import`s are discouraged. You should `import tkinter as tk` or `as` anything else you want.
- You are not passing the window(`Tk()`) to some of your widgets which is not a good practice.
- Making these improvements to your own already existing code might also help you out.